# Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, erc20

I'm trying to use ERC20 implementation of openzeppelin, but getting an error. tokenAddress is an address of the existing ERC20 token, for example USDC - 0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.4.0-solc-0.7/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

ERC20 token = ERC20(tokenAddress);
token.balanceOf(msg.sender);
```

An error

> revert    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note:
> The called function should be payable if you send value and the value
> you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the
> transaction to get more information.

Comment: The `0xA0b8...` address holds the contract on Ethereum mainnet. Does the error occur on the mainnet? Or are you trying to execute it on a different environment (e.g. Remix JS VM emulator, testnet, ...)?

Comment: I'm trying to execute in on the Remix

Comment: I'm looking for a solution where I can accept payments in the existing ERC20 tokens

Comment: The address of 0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48 is a USDC coin based on ERC20 interface

Answer (score 0):

The Remix VM emulator can't reach the contract deployed on the mainnet address - it's in a different environment.

However, you can fork the mainnet to your local environment, and then connect Remix to this local environment.

Here's an [article](https://medium.com/@samajammin/how-to-interact-with-ethereums-mainnet-in-a-development-environment-with-ganache-3d8649df0876) describing how to fork the Ethereum mainnet using Ganache.

One-click solution based on the article:

```
ganache-cli --fork https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{infura_project_id}
```

Then you can select a custom provider in your Remix IDE.

**ganache-cli is listening on port 8545, and Ganache UI on 7545.**

[image: Select Web3Provider]

Enter the local "Web3 Provider Endpoint" address with the port number `8545` (ganache-cli) or `7545` (Ganache UI).

[image: Local Web3 Provider]

Comment: I managed to instantiate tokens, but how I would get for payments some of them?