# Solidity: The transaction has been reverted to the initial state

Tags: solidity, contract

I have a separate function openTrading()

```
function openTrading() external onlyOwner() {
    require(!tradingOpen,"trading is already open");
        IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E);
    uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory())
    .createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());

    uniswapV2Router = _uniswapV2Router;
}
```

This was working fine few days ago. Now it is failing, debugging in JVM reveals it is failing at

```
_uniswapV2Router.factory()
```

**Error**:
*The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.*

I am completely lost, no idea why something that was working earlier now failing. To test this, I copied old deployed contract and it failed exact same place.

Could someone please suggest me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: On which environment is the transaction failing? E.g. Remix VM emulator, Ropsten testnet, ... if it's a public network (such as a testnet or the mainnet), please link the failing transaction.

Comment: I am running local JVM (London) environment.

Comment: The `0x10DE...` address doesn't hold the Uniswap contract in your local environment. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69101275/1693192) for a solution using a fork of the public environment.

Comment: I was able to use "0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1" router address in local VM and also in  testnet.bscscan.com. But now its not working. I want to be able to atlease test in testner environment.