# Why does my transaction revert when calling another contract function?

Tags: solidity

I am trying to call a function in an NFT contract deployed on Ethereum, with another contract in Remix, aiming to deploy that on Polygon.

This is the NFT function I want to call:

```
function allGenzeesOfWallet(address owner)
        public
        view
        returns (uint256[] memory)
    {
        uint256 tokenCount = balanceOf(owner);

        uint256[] memory tokensId = new uint256[](tokenCount);
        for (uint256 i; i < tokenCount; i++) {
            tokensId[i] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(owner, i);
        }
        return tokensId;
    }
```

And this is my new contract I'm writing to interact with it:

```
interface IGenzees {
    function allGenzeesOfWallet(address owner) external view returns(uint[] memory);
}

contract CallNFT {
    IGenzees public NFTcontract;

    constructor () {
        NFTcontract = IGenzees(0x201675fBFAAAC3A51371E4C31FF73Ac14ceE2A5A);
    }

    function getNoNFTsOwned(address user) public view returns(uint[] memory) {
        return NFTcontract.allGenzeesOfWallet(user);
    }
    function setNFTcontract(address addr) external { // Set NFT contract
        NFTcontract = IGenzees(addr);
    }
}
```

But when I call the getNoNFTsOwned function the console says:

```
call to CallNFT.getNoNFTsOwned errored: VM error: revert.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remix VM and Ethereum mainnet are two separate networks. It's not possible to reach a contract deployed on one network from the other.

You can set up a local **fork** from the mainnet, that effectively allows you to interact with your **local copy** of the mainnet contract from the Remix VM. You can find more info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69101275/1693192). Note: It won't affect the actual mainnet, just your local copy of the mainnet.

Comment: Thanks, so does my code look fine? And that must mean if I deploy my ERC20 token on Polygon I can't call the NFT contract on Ethereum?

Comment: @cryptoboi Your code is fine - the issue is in the application of the code (specifically, an unreachable network)... I'm not that much experienced in Polygon. From what I understand, it should be possible to **somehow** interact with the Ethereum mainnet from Polygon, because there is a bridge between the Polygon network and Ethereum. But most likely not from the get go, and it might require some additional setup.