# Chainlink Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, remix, chainlink

I am testing [this code](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-the-latest-price/#solidity) on Remix:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract PriceConsumerV3 {

    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;

    /**
     * Network: Kovan
     * Aggregator: ETH/USD
     * Address: 0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331
     */
    constructor() {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the latest price
     */
    function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int) {
        (
            uint80 roundID, 
            int price,
            uint startedAt,
            uint timeStamp,
            uint80 answeredInRound
        ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return price;
    }
}
```

Compilation and deployment seem to be executed correctly, however I receive this error:

> call to PriceConsumerV3.getLatestPrice errored: Returned error: VM
> Exception while processing transaction: revert

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my transaction revert when calling another contract function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70295764/why-does-my-transaction-revert-when-calling-another-contract-function)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error when deploying to the **Javascript VM**

[image: Deploying]

It's due to the contract you are trying to call not being available on the VM you are using. You'll need to switch to the **Injected Web3** option.

The deployment will also require having a wallet set up as you interact with an actual blockchain. The example you reference is using the Kovan Testnet.

Here are a few other links for reference

- [Metamask](https://metamask.io/)
- [Faucet if you need ETH](https://faucets.chain.link/)